# What is the difference between "Amazon Storage Gateway" and another storages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

I use "[Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com)" and I think about share storage with more instances "[Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2)". Data grows by client usage, and may be searched in those data.

Obviously I should use "[Elastic File System (EFS)](https://aws.amazon.com/efs)", but their pricing model is unpredictable to me, and questionable what happens if someone try search in 1TB of files. In second choice I can use "[Simple Storage Service (S3)](https://aws.amazon.com/s3)" but I'm not quite sure about speed towards "[Elastic Block Store (EBS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs)".

I find out just today AWS has service "[Storage Gateway (SG)](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway)". I understand that in background can be S3, ELB, tape" and it communicate through [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI).

**Q what is the difference between "Amazon Storage Gateway" and another storages?**

**Q what is difference between "connect #efs or #s3 direct to instances" and "connect instances through #sg " ?**

Comment: Storage Gateway is a (fancy) local proxy and cache for the stuff you store on S3, EBS, etc. It's not a storage solution on its own.

Comment: @ceejayoz thx like you wrote :-)

Answer (score 2):

EBS is block, EFS is file, S3 is object.

SG are fancy local caches and gateways to access the remote storage with familiar protocols.

SG still requires the other storage systems. If AWS is like a non-cloud remote storage array, SG is the filer and VTL options that speak file and tape.

Comment: I talk to friend yesterday and after I understand that like you wrote - it's just service gateway for many storages - thx. Q but I try ask again - what is difference connect #efs or #s3 direct to machines or through #sg ?